# Password protecting SSD drive

Tags: ssd, encryption

I have three hard drives in my computer, one SSD and two traditional hard drives. I just upgraded the SSD, the previous SSD was using TrueCrypt to encrypt it... which worked great. But this new SSD (a Samsung 840 EVO) was giving me issues with TrueCrypt. I did a little digging and many people recommend not using TrueCrypt with SSD drives.

I am just looking for basic protection, nothing fancy. What are my options? I've seen some mention that the 840 EVO is by default encrypted, I just have to add a password. In this scenario, if the hard drive is removed, will it still need a password to access the data?

Comment: If you are using Windows 7 or 8 you can always use Bitlocker.

Comment: Where did you read that you shouldn't use Truecrypt with SSDs because that's the ONLY way I would use them.  I should clarify.  I would only use SSDs with full disk based encryption because of the nature of wear leveling, and inability to guarantee, that deleted data could not be recovered.

Comment: Please elaborate on "giving me issues". There's no reason for TrueCrypt to have problems, though TrueCrypt in general is deprecated these days.

Comment: Forgot to mention, using Windows 7 home so no bitlocker

Comment: I was having random freezing every minute or so I would have 10 seconds of freeze. Tracked it down to this: http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?1062-Partial-system-freezing-%28input-still-responsive%29 (see toward bottom of the first page). But by the time I read this, I had already decrypted the drive

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [samsung site](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/about/whitepaper06.html):

> AES encryption is always active on an 840 or 840 Pro Series SSD. In order to benefit from the encryption feature, however, the user must enable an ATA password to limit access to the data. Failure to do so will render AES-encryption ineffective – akin to having a safe but leaving the door wide open.
>
> To set an ATA password, simply access the BIOS, navigate to the “Security” menu, enable “Password on boot” and set an “HDD Password.”

Comment: Unfortunately my BIOS doesn't have that option. My motherboard is a "ASRock P67 Extreme4 Gen3".

Comment: Seems it is a feature not present on most desktop machines, but mainly on laptops. So you could either use an external encryption mechanism (like truecrypt) or not use encryption at all. Or you could search for a motherboard that supports ATA encryption: http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-034023.htm

Comment: I was hoping someone would say it's still possible to use ATA password even if the BIOS doesn't support it.